# Maintaining data class when using zoo package function na.locf to fill values

Tags: r, zoo

I am using the zoo package to fill NA values with previous data.  This works great, except that the resulting filled data frame seems to be coerced to characters from dates and numeric.

**My question:**  Is there a way to maintain the original data class and not have the data coerced into characters?

**My reproducible example** (simplified version of how I receive my data):

```
# Packages
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

# Data
mydates <- as.Date(c("2017-06-28", "2017-06-29", "2017-06-30", "2017-07-01", "2017-07-02", "2017-07-03", "2017-07-04", "2017-07-05"))
item_1  <- c(180.6692, 180.6755, 180.6823, NA, NA, 180.7014, 180.7081, NA)
item_2  <- c(1295.1, 1293.019, 1290.876, NA, NA, 1288.256, NA, NA)
item_3 <-  c(1693.05, 1686.481, 1681.491, NA, NA, 1675.35, NA, NA)

# Data frame
df <- data.frame(mydates, item_1, item_2, item_3)

# Fill NAs with previous value
df_fill <- df %>%
  na.locf()

# Correct data class
str(df)

# Incorrect data class from filling NA values
str(df_fill)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some alternative solutions. (1) and its variations perform `na.locf` on each column separately whereas (2) and its variation converts the data frame to zoo, applies `na.locf` and converts back.  (If you knew that there were no leading NAs in any column then `na.rm = FALSE` could optionally be omitted in these solutions.)

**1)** Perform `na.locf` on each column separately.  Only zoo is needed. It modifies `df` in place.  All othre solutions give output answer without modifying the inputs.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE)
```

**1a)** Similar except it does not modify `df`

```
replace(df, TRUE, lapply(df, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE))
```

**1b)**  Similar but uses %>% from magrittr or dplyr:

```
df %>% replace(., TRUE, lapply(., na.locf, na.rm = FALSE))
```

**2)** convert to zoo, apply `na.locf` and convert back to data frame.  Only zoo is needed.

```
fortify.zoo(na.locf(read.zoo(df), na.rm = FALSE))
```

**2a)** Similar but uses magrittr or dplyr

```
df %>% read.zoo %>% na.locf(na.rm = FALSE) %>% fortify.zoo
```